# SDL Addon Libraries not Linking Correctly

Tags: c++, mingw, sdl, linker-errors, codeblocks

I tried to link SDL_mixer, SDL_ttf, and SDL_image to my project, but for some reason, these errors pop up when compiling my code. The header files that I included depend on the libraries above it. I linked to my library in this order:

MinGW32
OpenGL32
SDLmain
SDL
SDL_image
SDL_ttf
SDL_mixer

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <SDL/SDL.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_mixer.h>
#include <SDL/SDL_ttf.h>

using namespace std;

#include "include_file.h"
#include "structure.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "healthclass.h"
#include "items.h"
#include "loadfiles.h"
#include "init_game.h"
#include "missions.h"
```

Then the error:

```
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x16e): undefined reference to `Mix_LoadMUS'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x197): undefined reference to `Mix_LoadWAV_RW'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1c0): undefined reference to `Mix_LoadWAV_RW'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x1e9): undefined reference to `Mix_LoadWAV_RW'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x7cd): undefined reference to `IMG_Load'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x996): undefined reference to `TTF_RenderUTF8_Shaded'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20ca): undefined reference to `Mix_CloseAudio'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x20cf): undefined reference to `TTF_Quit'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x2f7b): undefined reference to `IMG_Load'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3788): undefined reference to `TTF_Init'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x37ac): undefined reference to `Mix_OpenAudio'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3914): undefined reference to `TTF_OpenFont'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x3983): undefined reference to `Mix_PlayMusic'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x61f0): undefined reference to `Mix_PlayChannelTimed'
obj\Release\main.o:main.cpp:(.text+0x6330): undefined reference to `Mix_Playing'
```

Comment: How are you linking to the libraries? For the most part you can just include the static LIB file with the project and the DLL file with the result, or you can dynamically link (using sdl-config's Windows equivalent).

Comment: I used lazyfoo's tutorial, where I linked to the lib files. http://lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/windows/codeblocks/index.php

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out that I was trying to compile a 32bit version of SDL with a 64bit version of SDL_image, SDL_mixer, and SDL_ttf. So, when you are installing the add-on library, use the x86 folder instead of the x64 folder when installing the library files. It doesn't matter if you have a 64bit computer, if SDL is 32bit then use the x86 lib folder, unless you know what you're doing, which I didn't.